# Histogram Equalization Problems

Tags: java, project, histogram

I'm working on a project in which I'm trying to use histogram equalization to do something like going from this image

http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/input-300x200.jpg

"http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/hist_before.png"

to this image

http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/output-300x200.jpg

"http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/hist_after.png"

but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is my enhanced image code which should implement the same type of adjustment..

```
public void EnhancedImage (File fileName) {

           double sumc = 0;
            for(int r = 0; r < array.length; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < array[r].length; c++){ 
                    sumc = r+c;
                    if (sumc <= array[r][c]) {
                     sumc = array[r][c];
                    }
                        newc = Math.round(maxshade * ((double)sumc / pixtot));
                        array[r][c] = (int) (newc);
                        if (array[r][c] > 255) {
                            array[r][c] = 255;
                    }
                }

                }
```

The algorithm that i would like to use is below where maxShade is the maximum shade of the image (usually 255) sumc is the total number of pixels in the image with a value less than or equal to c and pixtot is the total number of pixels in the picture:

```
newc := round(maxShade * ((double)sumc / pixtot))
```

but im not sure if i did it right...currently my image just turns really dark.

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks.

Also my pixtot routine:

```
 pixtot = 0;
           for(int y = 0; y < imageArray.length; y++)
                for(int x = 0; x < imageArray[0].length; x++)
                    pixtot = x+y;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
pixtot = x+y;
```

First, you want `+=`, not `=`.  Second, this is adding up the *indexes* of the pixels, not the *value* of the pixels.  You want something like

```
pixtot += imageArray[y][x];
```

You make the same conceptual error with `sumc`.

**Edit:**

There's lots of other problems with your code.  If you want to stretch the dynamic range, you want to compute `min` and `max`, the minimum and maximum of all the pixel values, then compute each pixel value as `value = maxshade * (value - min) / (max - min)`.  That gives you a result pixel value of `0` if `value==min` and `maxshade` if `value==max`.

This doesn't really give you histogram equalization, however.  For that you need to compute a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) of the input pixel values and compute quantiles in that histogram to figure out the output values, it isn't easy.

Comment: i tried pixtot += imageArray[r][c]; but i got an index out of bounds exception.... then also what do you mean same conceptual error with sumc? just adding the += and changing my variables to array values? and pixtot is supposed to add up all the pixels in the image... not the values of the grayscales

Comment: Then you want `pixtot++` if you're counting the total number of pixels, not the total values of the pixels (of course, there are shorter ways of doing that using multiply).

Comment: alright im starting to get this thing to work but when i run enhanced it turns the image completely black ...   to be honest im not sure if i have a function that groups the grayscale values properly such as a CDF function.. im not sure how to implement it --- i need it to count up all the grayscale values for example 133 and  total them then check to see if they are less than or equal to the grayscale value in that slot and run my equation..

Comment: i have already computed those items in this project i have a min and max function as well as that exact equation you use to display a simple contrast of my image -- that all works perfectly.  I am just working on a more in depth contrast of the image and needed some help figuring out why its not working.